# How to relate table with one of many others?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, erd

I am little confused about my db design. I have `orders` table that may have records from one of many others. So is it OK to relate each tables with 1:1 to `orders`. Please look at `orders` `domains` and `hostings` table relations.

My `orders` table rows has either a `domain` or `hosting` regarding to its `orders_type` value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if the orders should have 1:1 relationship with domains and another 1:1 relationship with hostings?  If you are, the answer is no.  Your hosting table has an orders_id which implies means that you can have multiple hostings with the same order, i.e., orders:hosting is 1:M.

{Regarding domains, orders:domains =>  1:M}

Comment: Yes I am asking that and saying an order can only have a hosting record or a domain record. Cannot have multiple hostings and/or multiple domains in one record. Is that relation wrong?

Comment: You want one order to have only one hosting or only one domain AND never both.  Put a domain_id and a hosting_id field in your orders table.  The database will ensure that you can have only one domain or one hosting.  Your application needs to ensure that you do not try to put one of each in the database. (Technically, you could put a trigger on the table to enforce that business rule.)

Comment: Then, hosting_id would be empty if order is a domain order. There would be almost 10 different products which are not seeing on diagram yet. Wouldn't it be a bad design to create a column for every product? Should I use TRIGGER to go with upper diagram?

Comment: Products? {For now forget about the idea of the trigger.} Are you saying that there will be at least 8 more tables defined? Why aren't they in the above diagram?  If so, do you really need 10 tables, or can less be used because fields overlap?

Comment: This diagram is just first draft and I am building structure at first. Consider there will be `servers` `ssl_products` `vps` `licences` `security_products` tables like `domains` and `hostings`. An `orders` record would have only one of them and it will be decided by its `orders_types_id`. I am thinking about every those products would have 1:1 relationship with `orders` table. I am not sure will it be OK or what should I do.

Comment: (IMHO) At this point, my recommendation: use your best guess and implement.  Just don't do anything that breaks the first three Boyce-Codd normal forms.  THEN be prepared to refactor your database. The simple truth is nearly all development I have been involved in has been refactored for one reason or another (e.g., business rules change, business value changes, technology changes, assumptions were wrong, just plain wrong solution.)