# Is it possible to relate one table to one of a group of tables based off of id using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Here is a diagram of what I'm looking for first off:

[image: Diagram of Generic Object]
So I have the MainObject, and the main object could be related to EntityA, EntityB, OR EntityC.  As an example...

Let's say MainObject is an invoice. 
EntityA, EntityB, and EntityC are all different entities that can be invoiced.
So I have the following options:

**(A)** I can have EntityA_Id, EntityB_Id, EntityC_Id columns on the MainObject table to relate with.

**(B)** I can have Entity_Id and EntityType_Id on the MainObject table that tells me if EntityType_Id = 1 then I need the EntityA object with Id of Entity_Id.

With **A** I can use simple `MainObject.Include("EntityA").Include("EntityB").Include("EntityC")..` when retrieving the MainObject through Entity Framework - however I then have to do null checks on everything to find out exactly what it is that is tied to MainObject.

With **B** is it possible to do something similar to A so that I don't have at multiple null fields for every MainObject object when trying to figure out what it is related to?

This is similar to [How to relate table with one of many others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080192/how-to-relate-table-with-one-of-many-others) but as I understand it, that is trying to relate many to many through a linker table, whereas each MainObject will be related to one of A, B, or C (and A, B, and C can be related to many MainObjects).  To use the linked question as an example, one order would be linked to one hosting OR one domain, and would go through the type table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after a Table Per Heirarchy design (TPH).
See [this good explanation](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

The following will create a MainObjects table with a discriminator column

```
public class Model1Context : DbContext
{
    public Model1Context()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {

    }
    // For TPH
    public virtual DbSet<BaseBO> MainObjects { get; set; }

    // For TPT
    //public virtual DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    //public virtual DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class BaseBO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A : BaseBO
{
}

public class B : BaseBO
{
}

public class C : BaseBO
{
}
```

If you prefer to have separate tables in the database for each class then switch to Table Per Type (TPT)

Comment: Wow, this is a treasure trove.  This is definitely useful, and if I find my answer in here I'll be back to accept this as the answer.

Comment: The TPT approach appears to be what I'm looking for, however the entities are in tables that have already been populated and our current practices are using database first modeling - I'm looking to implement the link and inheritance.  A coworker is arguing that it would be more "industry standard" to just have a table with a column for the id of each type of entity we're wanting to link to (so EntityId, AId, BId, CId, etc. in each record, only EntityId and one of the other columns having a value)  and use relationships instead of implementing inheritance.  Is this feasible in database first?

Comment: I just edited this example to remove the dangerous initializer strategy since you wont want to drop the database.   You may like to reverse engineer your current data structure using the "Code First from database" option in the Entity Data Model Wizard.